# Change font color for a column when the value changes

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

if i have a column where the values are repeated across rows and i want to change the color of the font when the value changes, how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can define an expression for the font color.  In Visual Studio/Business Intellligence:

1. Select the cell you want to alter the colour of the font in
2. Navigate to the **Color** listing in the **Properties**, and select it
3. Click the Dropdown arrow that appears next to the value it's current set to (typically Black)
4. Under the **Web** tab, select **Expression** (top of the list) - the Edit Expression dialog will appear
5. You can use the IIF in combination with the [PREVIOUS function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156372.aspx) to compare values.  IE:

   ```
   =IIF(Fields!Registrations.Value <> Previous(Fields!Registrations.Value), 
         "Black", 
         "Blue")
   ```

   If true, this expression will colour the font black -- if false, blue.