# Change font color for a row when the value is one specific value

Tags: formatting, ssrs-2008, bids

I'm trying to change the font color on complete row when a value. I found the question and answer for changing the font color on a particular cell on another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096455/change-font-color-for-a-column-when-the-value-changes/3096563#3096563).

This was part of the other answer:

> =IIF(Fields!Registrations.Value <> Previous(Fields!Registrations.Value), 
>         "Black", 
>         "Blue")

but it won't do what I need. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the color of an entire row, you would just select the entire row and choose expression under colors in the property menu, just as the article you linked described. If you want the color to change when that row has a particular value for a particular field, you would use an expression more like this:

```
=iif(yourField.Value = yourValue, yourColor1, yourColor2)
```

Comment: Thanks TPhe! I actually figured it out over the weekend but didn't get a chance to come back to answer my own question. :-)